# Constraint method on field not called

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

why is my constraint on project_id never called? The info is never shown and a breakpoint never triggered. I want to constrain the projects that are shown in the form in the project select. project_id is the following defined in in hr_timesheet.

```py
project_id = fields.Many2one('project.project', 'Project',
                             domain=[('allow_timesheets', '=', True)])
```

My constrain in own module

```py
class AccountAnalyticLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.analytic.line'

    @api.one
    @api.constrains('project_id')
    def constrain_project_id(self):
        raise exceptions.ValidationError('Working')
        # all records passed the test, don't return anything
```

How can I make my constrain working? I have tried to define project_id in my own module again to override the original but still not called. Also not called after removing the domain.

Comment: the constrains methods are only called when you make a change in the `project_id ` field. One more thing, don't us `@api.one`

Comment: So, `project_id` belongs to the `hr.timesheet` model and your `constrain_project_id` belongs to `account.analytic.line`? There's no way Odoo will pick that! Are you familiar with domains? (https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#domains) Maybe that's what you want.